# Manipulating list index value, What is wrong with this python code?

Tags: python-3.x

My intention is to change the index value of the list1; list1 changes the value but at two different locations instead of just one. list2 does what I want to do with list 1.

```
list1 = []
list2 = [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]


def append_values():

    amount = None

    if len(list1) == 0:
        amount = 70
        list1.append([[40],amount])
    else:
        amount = 90
        list1.append([list1[-1],amount])



def alter_lists():

    print('ori: ', list1) #Orginal list
    list1[1][0][1] = "alt"
    print('alt: ', list1)   #Altered list

    print('\n')

    print('ori: ', list2) #Orginal list
    list2[1][0][1] = 'alt'
    print('alt: ', list2)  #Altered list


append_values()
append_values()
alter_lists()
```

Output:

**list1**

```
   ori:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]
   alt:  [[[40], 'alt'], [[[40], 'alt'], 90]]
```

**list2**

```
ori:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]
alt:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 'alt'], 90]]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're appending list itself in the `if` block. So when you mutate the appended list in `else` block it mutates all references to the original list. What you need is a deepcopy, as below:

```
import copy

list1 = []
list2 = [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]


def append_values():
    amount = None


    if len(list1) == 0:
        amount = 70
        list1.append([[40],amount])

    else:
        amount = 90
        l = copy.deepcopy(list1)
        list1.append([l[-1],amount])



def alter_lists():

    print('ori: ', list1) #Orginal list
    list1[1][0][1] = "alt"
    print('alt: ', list1)   #Altered list

    print('\n')

    print('ori: ', list2) #Orginal list
    list2[1][0][1] = 'alt'
    print('alt: ', list2)  #Altered list


append_values()
append_values()
alter_lists()
```

Gives:

```
ori:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]
alt:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 'alt'], 90]]


ori:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 70], 90]]
alt:  [[[40], 70], [[[40], 'alt'], 90]]
```